# Turn a color to black if its r+b > 150

Tags: php

I've looked around on SO but I couldn't find any similar question.

After opening an image in PHP I'm willing to check every pixel, and, if their red + green values is lower than 150 I would turn that pixel to white, instead if the sum is higher than 150 I would turn that pixel to black.

Is this possible?

I've tried with `imagefilter()` but I can't make it work as expected. Maybe there are more appropriate functions to use.

Comment: In GD it's probably hard to do it without setting individual pixels. Have you tried a combination of `Imagick::whiteThresholdImage` & `Imagick::blackThresholdImage` ?

Comment: How can I adapt it to red + green > 150?

Comment: I am not entirely sure you can, these 2 just _seem_ to me like a start-off point (hence, not an answer and just a comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng($img);
$xdim = imagesx($image);
$ydim = imagesy($image);
for ($x = 1; $x <= $xdim-1; $x++) {
    for ($y = 1; $y <= $ydim-1; $y++) {
        $rgb = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
        if($rgb>150)
            $color = 0x00;
        else
            $color = 0xFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This does what the user wanted. But I would warn that there is something wrong when you need to do something as slow as this. Try seeing if you can't make use of pre-built functions as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

Look at using the imagecolorat function (I think it may be part of the GD library).  You can get the RGB from that.  Then use imagecolorset to set the new RGB.